# Inmobi Banner Ad sizes

Tags: java, android, inmobi

I am trying to integrate Inmobi banner ads into my app programmatically but I'm having a problem regarding the size of the banner ad. I have the following code snippet in my Launcher class:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams bannerLp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        bannerLp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
        bannerLp.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
        layout.addView(bannerAd, bannerLp);
        setContentView(layout);
        bannerAd.load();
```

It doesn't show any ad on phone. But when I set the hight parameter from WRAP_CONTENT to 80. It fits perfectly at the bottom. But when tried same on a phone with bigger screen size, it appears small. 
I used the same code snippet for AdMob ads and havent faced this difficulty. I had always set the with parameter as MATCH_PARENT and height parameter as WRAP_CONTENT. Why is it no displaying anything when using Inmobi?

Answer (score 1):

According to InMobi integration [guide](https://support.inmobi.com/monetize/android-guidelines/banner-ads-for-android/) :

> You should specify the banner view dimensions in pixel units when
>   setting the layout parameters for the banner ad. Also, it is a
>   programming error to supply WRAP_CONTENT as the layout parameters for
>   a banner ad. This constraint applies whether you create a banner in
>   your XML layout resource file or in code.

Comment: So what values should I provide as the parameters so that the ads don't fail to load or appear too small/big?

Comment: you can calculate dimension of your screen or view and use that value as parameters.

Comment: Okay I gave the parameters 640, 100 as given in their documentation. It displays correctly in a medium screen size phone but appears too small in a bigger size screen

Comment: increase value of 640,100 in proportion according to screen size

Comment: I will have to adjust the parameters individually for every screen size?

Comment: you can use `0.8*w` and `0.07*h` for portrait mode, where w and h are width and height of screen respectively